# Is there a way to use a variable as a function?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to replace a lot of things in a string, but i dont want to write "Replace" everytime

```
Sub test()
Let b = "replace"
Let a = "abc"
Debug.Print Evaluate(b(b(a, "a", "b"), "b", "d"))
End Sub
```

Is there a way to set "b" to be evaluated like a function?
Or assign a function to a variable and then use it?

I know i can use this

```
Sub test()
Let b = "replace"
Let a = "abc"
With WorksheetFunction
  x = .Substitute(.Substitute(a, "a", "b"), "b", "d")
Debug.Print x
End Sub
```

But would be the same thing, write "Substitute" all time

The actual code is bigger than this, this is just an example

Comment: Btw, `Let` is deprecated. Feel free to remove it.

Comment: Why not just write a function? `Function b(ByRef foo As String) As String`?

Comment: @BigBen i thought in write it, but would write a function just for that, btw, if there is a way to do it, would do the same thing for other projects, not just the replace function

Comment: I fail to see the issue you have. Is the problem just that you don't want to type all the letters for the function's names?

Comment: @VincentG as i said, the code is bigger than that, would substitute a lot of things in the same string, so write something like b(a,"a","b") would be easier instead write "Substitute" all the time

Comment: This smells very much like an XY problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the case of `Replace`, I suggest just writing a new function:

```
Function b( _
    ByRef Expression As String, _
    ByRef Find As String, _
    ByRef Replace As String _
) As String
    
    b = VBA.Replace(Expression, Find, Replace)
End Function


Sub test()
    Dim a As String
    a = "abc"
    
    Debug.Print b(b(a, "a", "b"), "b", "d")
End Sub
```

---

However...

> I want to replace a lot of things in a string, but i dont want to write "Replace" everytime.

Seems like an XY problem. Use two arrays and a loop:

```
Sub test2()
    Dim oldLetters As Variant
    oldLetters = Array("a", "b")
    
    Dim newLetters As Variant
    newLetters = Array("b", "d")
    
    Dim a As String
    a = "abc"
    
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(oldLetters) To UBound(oldLetters)
        a = Replace(a, oldLetters(i), newLetters(i))
    Next
    
    Debug.Print a
End Sub
```